# jQuery button same function with link

Tags: jquery

the jQuery is

```
$(function() {
    // videoThumb is a css class found in the foreach list class="videoThumb". ytvideo is the holder ID set as div ID
    $(".videoThumb4").on('click').ytplaylist({
        holderId: 'ytvideo4',
        html5: true,
        playerWidth: '520',
        autoPlay: false,
        sliding: false,
        listsliding: true,
        social: true,
        autoHide: false,
        playfirst: 0,
        playOnLoad: false,
        modestbranding: true,
        showInfo: false
    });
});
```

the main clickable link  is this

```
<a class="videoThumb4" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $yValue['videoid'] . '">
    ' . $yValue['description'] . '
</a>
```

then i want this link to be like a button which is below. with same value and function.
is this correct the button is

```
<input class="videoThumb4" onclick="ytplaylist();" type="button" name="previewSel" value="Preview" id="previewbut">
```

the sample link was [YT](http://cocopop12.site11.com/search/)

Comment: I don't think you can use HTML comments in javascript or use `.` for concatenating. **UPDATE:** @roko has changed the code. @Roko: You shouldn't do that. Maybe that is the problem and then everyone might say that it works

Answer (score 0):

Since the jQuery selector for the function is written using the css class name, you simply need to give the same class name to the element. Remove the onlick event as the functionality is already bounded in the ready event.

You were also missing a closing tag for the button element.

```
<input class="videoThumb4" type="button" 
                           name="previewSel" value="Preview" id="previewbut" />
```

Comment: hi Shyju thank you for your reply. i try your suggestion but the video is still not playing. here is the sample website for the pplugins that im working for [link]http://cocopop12.site11.com/search/index.php